# Is this a cast or a construction?

Tags: c++, casting, constructor

I'm a little confused after reading something in a textbook.  Regarding the code:

```
void doSomeWork(const Widget& w)
{
    //Fun stuff.
}

doSomeWork(Widget(15));
```

`doSomeWork()` takes a `const Widget&` parameter.  The textbook, Effective C++ III, states that this creates a temporary Widget object to pass to doSomeWork.  It says that this can be replaced by:

```
doSomeWork(static_cast<Widget>(15));
```

as both versions are casts - the first is just a function-style C cast apparently.  I would have thought that `Widget(15)` would invoke a constructor for widget taking one integer parameter though.

Would the constructor be executed in this case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++ this kind of expression *is* a form of a cast, at least syntactically. I.e. you use a C++ functional cast syntax `Widget(15)` to create a temporary object of type `Widget`.

Even when you construct a temporary using a multi-argument constructor (as in `Widget(1, 2, 3)`) it is still considered a variation of *functional cast* notation (see 5.2.3)

In other words, your "Is this a cast or a construction" question is incorrectly stated, since it implies mutual exclusivity between casts and "constructions". They are not mutually exclusive. In fact, every type conversion (be that an explicit cast or something more implicit) is nothing else than a creation ("construction") of a new temporary object of the target type (excluding, maybe, some reference initializations).

BTW, functional cast notation is a chiefly C++ notation. C language has no functional-style casts.

Answer (score 5):

Short: Yes.

Long:

You can always test those things yourself, by doing e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

struct W
{
    W( int i )
    {
        std::cout << "W(" << i << ")\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    W w(1);
    W(2);
    static_cast<W>(3);
}
```

which is outputting

```
W(1)
W(2)
W(3)
```

Comment: @MSalters: That for most types a cast is no different than creating a (temporary) object.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is both :). A cast is a syntactic construct (i.e. something you type). In this case, a constructor is invoked as a consequence of the cast. Much like a constructor would be invoked as a consequence of typing

```
Widget w(15);
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `Widget(15)` and `static_cast<Widget>(15)` are casts, or conversion
operators, if you prefer.  Both create a new object of the designated
type, by converting `15` into a `Widget`.  Since `15` doesn't have any
conversion operators, the only way to do this conversion is by
allocating the necessary memory (on the stack) and calling the
appropriate constructor.  This is really no different that `double(15)`
and `static_cast<double>(15)`, except that we usually don't think of
`double` as having a constructor (but the resulting `double` is a new
object, distinct from the `15`, which has type `int`).

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> the first is just a function-style C cast apparently

The first would not **compile** in C, it's not C-style. C-style looks like `(Widget)15`. Here, the temporary object is created, using `Widget::Widget(int)`.

Therefore, it is not a C-style cast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Any constructor takes a single parameter would be considered as CONVERSION CONSTRUCTOR. Your constructor is already taking a single `int` parameter, so that the compiler can "implicitly" call this constructor to match the argument (with the value `15`, which is `int`).

There is a simple trick to prevent such errors, just use the keyword `explicit` before your constructor.

Check [this](http://www.glenmccl.com/tip_023.htm) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Yeeeah. You can replace

```
Widget(15)
```

with

```
static_cast<Widget>(15)
```

Because it will be replaced back by compiler :D

When you cast `int` to `Widget` compiler looks for `Widget::Widget(int);` and place it there.